# Where does the tikz package belong in TexShop

Tags: tikz-pgf, packages, texshop

A few years ago, I managed to write LaTeX code with e.g. `\usepackage{tikz} ....\[\begin{tikzpicture} \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (8,8); \end{tikzpicture}/]`. The corresponding file compiles in TeXShop on my computer. My collaborator cannot get it to compile on his Mac which has an up to date version of TeXShop installed. I recall that when I first started with this method, I had to move something into an appropriate directory within TeXShop. I don't recall what it was or how I moved it so I can't help my collaborator fix his problem. Where does the tikz package belong in TexShop?

Comment: It isn't TeXshop that uses the packages like tikz; it's LaTeX (pdflatex/xelatex) itself. Do you know what TeX distribution your collaborator is using? They should use the package manager for their distribution to install TikZ if possible.

Comment: If your collaborator is using TeXShop and doesn't have TikZ installed then it's most likely that they have installed the small version of MacTeX called BasicTeX. If that's the case they should use the TeX Live Utility or command line `tlmgr` to install TikZ. But unless they have real reasons to need BasicTeX, they'd probably be better off installing a full MacTeX than having to worry about installing things at all.

Comment: Just to be clear: do simple documents compile for your collaborator? e.g. `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}\end{document}`? If not, then the problem is simply that they've only installed TeXShop and not MacTeX.

Comment: Yes Alan, thanks for your question. The file is complete on at least one machine. There is some missing voodoo on making sure that my collaborator can compile the tikz picture. My feeling is that your first comment addresses the need for additional voodoo.

Comment: Alan's original comment seemed to have solved the problem.